# How to package a C++/WinRT executable for installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++-winrt

I built a C++/WinRT app and when trying to start the Release build executable I get the error

".. MSVCP140_APP.DLL was not found"  followed by ".. VCRUNTIME140_APP.DLL was not found".

Obviously the runtime is installed on my development machine and I can launch it from Visual Studio using Ctrl+F5.

What more should I do to make this binary a package that can be deployed? It's an independent executable with no other external library dependencies.

I tried going through the docs and searching the web, but couldn't find any clues. I suspect executable packaging has changed with Windows 10 as I'm coming back to Windows development after leaving it during early Win 7 days.

Comment: Digging through the docs I have learned that MS is moving away from MSI into APPX for application deployment. And VS2017 has a neat feature to generate the APPX bundle for a project right from project's options (Store -> Create App Packages...). This produces a folder with all the necessary files that can then be distributed for deployment. Question is -- is there anyway this can be bundled as a single binary that the user can click to install? My requirement is a LOB package that won't be deployed through the Store.

Comment: Here's the link to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

Comment: The MSIX installer technology allows you to package APPX packages for custom distribution. There's *very* little information available, a Microsoft Build 2018 video [MSIX: Inside and Out](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2018/BRK2432), the [Universal Windows App Deployment blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/), as well as the [MSIX Packaging SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/msix-packaging) GitHub repo is about all I could come up with. You'll have to start digging from here.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look.